# Ruby on Rails DB entry in a model (RoR 3)

Tags: ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-3, model

Skip to EDIT2 which works

There is:

- Project (has_many :group_permissions)
- GroupPermission (belongs_to :project)

I have a form where you can create a new project. A project has several attributes like name, status etc. and now important: iit. iit is selectable with radio buttons: yes or no.

What I want:

If someone selects **yes** on iit in the Project form, there should be a new record in GroupPermission. So in EVERY project where iit= 1 there should be a certain GroupPermisson.

Can I make / check this in the GroupPermission model? Like if

```
class GroupPermission < ActiveRecord::Base
    if Project.where(iit: 1)
     make me a record for each project

end
```

Can I even make database entries in the model like so?

Is this the right way?

**EDIT1:**

In the Project controller I added:

```
if params[:iit] = 1
    record = GroupPermission.new(cn: 'ccc-ml', project_id: params[:id])
    record.save
end
```

It then adds a new record in GroupPermissions. But I need the :id of the project. How can I access the id of the project which is about to be saved?

**EDIT2**

In the Project Controller

```
after_filter :iit_test, :only => [:create]
  ...

private

 def iit_test
   if @trial.iit == 1
   record = GroupPermission.new(cn: 'ccc-ml', project_id: @project.id, name: 'CATEGORY_3')
   record.save
 end
```

end

EDIT2 works fine. I just have to check it with update etc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `EDIT2` will only work for apis hitting the controller and not when you add a project via rails console, use in tests etc.

Also this `:iit_test` will not correctly work for `update action` as you are creating a new GroupPermission everytime. (GroupPermission may already exists for this project)

You should probably add a callback `after_save` in the project model and handle adding of a new GroupPermission there.

Comment: Yeah thats right. But I solved it for create, update and destroy. Now it works perfectelly.

Comment: after_save takes care of create and update. I feel you don't have to create a new GroupPermission for destroyed project.

To handle deletion of project you can add this to the association in project model (project.rb)


`has_many :group_permissions, :dependent => :destroy `

Answer (score 0):

Write a before action in Project controller like below

```
def find_project
 @project = Project.find_by(id: params[:id])
end
```

by calling above method in before action you will get the instance of the Project.

Hence you can create the Group Permission by

```
def create_group_permission
 @project.group_permissions.create(cn: 'ccc-ml')
end
```

The above will create a GroupPermission record with a project id which was found in before action.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot find the id of params if it is not saved before. So I use `after_filter` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a method in your `projects_controller`, you can move the logic to a seperate service. That will make your code easy to test etc..

Something like..

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @project = ProjectService.create(project_params)  
    # rest of your controller code
  end
end

#app/services
class ProjectService

  def self.create(project_params)
    project = Project.new(project_params)
    if project.save && project.iit == 1
      GroupPermission.create(cn: 'ccc-ml', project_id: project.id, name: 'CATEGORY_3') 
    end
    project
  end  

end
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. I haven't worked with `services` so far so I will keep that in mind for my next project. So far my approach works as expected.